# MTBF calculation with 2 units connected in series

Tags: logic

Me and a friend have a opinion difference regarding a question that got asked in a previous IT test.

The short version:

2 units, `n` and `m` are connected in series but operate as one system. `n` has a MTBF of 200, `m` of 300. What is the MTBF of the entire system?

possible solutions:

- 200
- 250
- 300
- 500

I am convinced (as is the guy who made the question) that the correct answer is 250.

My friend is convinced it is 120 and the question contains a mistake.

How were I to calculate this?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What's your reasoning why 250 is the right answer?  What's your friend's argument that 120 is the correct answer?  How did you approach the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the MTBF of a device is $N$, then the probability that the device will fail in 1 time unit is $1/N$. With two devices in series with failure probabilities $p_1$ and $p_2$, the system will fail in one time unit if device 1 fails or if device 1 doesn't fail and device 2 fails. The probability of that happening is
$$
p_1 + (1-p_1)p_2=p_1+p_2-p_1p_2
$$
In your problem, $p_1=1/200, p_2=1/300$ so the probability that the system will fail in one time unit is 
$$
(1/200)+(1/300)-(1/200)(1/300)=499/60000\approx0.00832
$$
and so the MTBF of the whole system is $1/0.00832\approx120.24$. Your friend is right: none of the proposed solutions are correct.